# Windows 10 make UAC always require password

Tags: windows-10, uac

I want to make my UAC to always require admin password. I seen some tutorials for windows 7, and with gpedit, however I have home version and gpedit is not included and I couldn't find any tutorial without it. Is it possible to do it through regedit?

Comment: Are you signed in as an admin?

Comment: Yes however I want to force asking for password even for admin because I am running teamviewer and I want to make sure that even in case someone would get into control he would need to know admin password

Comment: Have you tried the .reg files available [here?](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/41136-uac-change-prompt-behavior-administrators-windows.html)

Comment: I didn't found this site before, but I checked it now and it's working

Comment: Do you mind if I post it as an answer?

Comment: How you add gpedit to Home versions of Windows is well documented there is even a question with an answer that explains in detail how to do it.

Comment: Do you have `secpol.msc` ("Local Security Policy")? It contains the relevant portion of the Group Policy editor, but not most of the rest. It's present on Windows RT (the crippled ARM-only version of Win8); I'd be surprised if it's not on Win10 Home.

Comment: @CBHacking I just tried to run `secpol.msc` and I got message that it `can not be found`

Comment: Sad, guess it's missing from Home edition then. I'm mildly curious if it would work if you copied it from a higher edition (Pro, Education, Enterprise, anything Server, etc.) since I'm pretty sure Home has `mmc.exe` (and if it doesn't, maybe you could copy that...) but the direct registry edit works fine, too.

Comment: @CBHacking I believe it is possible, however I didn't wanted to modify system's files as the machine that I own is under warranty which disallows me to modify system files etc.

Comment: Copy unmodified files from one machine to another hardly counts as "modifying system files", and most warranties *cannot* prohibit you from such modifications regardless (at least in the US) but it sounds like you've solved the issue regardless.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is controlled by the registry entry here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
```

And you want the value of:

```
"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"=dword:00000001
```

[Source](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/41136-uac-change-prompt-behavior-administrators-windows.html)

[ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin's value reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232761.aspx)

Comment: You're not serious are you? Such an important setting and you have to use a fiddly  registry hack????? There must be another way.

Answer (score 5):

You can paste this snippet into an *Administrative* PowerShell prompt:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" -Value 1
```

The `Set-ItemProperty` command is essentially used to change values of registries. The rest of the parameters of the prompt are relatively intuitive, but I'll go through the rest.

As seen in other answers/responses, the path of the registry (can also be accessed with `regedit`) is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` - but in this case `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is shortened to `HKLM` and appended with `:`. So in order to access the registry, we use the `-Path` option (or *flag*) to note that the following string (surrounded by quotes `"`) is the desired path of the registry we want to update.

The next option we need to pass is `-Name`. Which (you guessed it) is for the name of the value we want to update. So now naturally we pass in the value `"ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin"`. The quotes are necessary because the `-Name` option expects a string value.

Finally, we set the `-Value` *value* to `1`. Which by the Windows 10 operating system interprets this as: "Let's basically just always ask for administrative permission for administrative tasks."

*Or in their words*:

> This option prompts the Consent Admin to enter his or her user name and password (or another valid admin) when an operation requires elevation of privilege. This operation occurs on the secure desktop.

Source for registry details: [Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpsb/341747f5-6b5d-4d30-85fc-fa1cc04038d4).

Comment: This is basically a copy of the accepted answer but using Powershell.

Comment: Similar content, yes. But definitely a different method to achieve the desired result. @CaldeiraG, I would suggest this is a fully appropriate answer since it contributes to the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

An even simpler or easier way is once you find the Value name: block, "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin" go to the block below which is Value data: and change the number to a "1". It gives you the same result.

ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin

This key defines the User Account Control behavior for system administrators. The default value is set to prompt but do not require credentials to be entered. Here are all possible values:

- 0: A value of 0 allows administrators to perform operations that require elevation without consent (meaning prompts) or credentials (meaning authentication).
- 1: A value of 1 requires the admin to enter username and password when operations require elevated privileges on a secure desktop.
- 2: The value of 2 displays the UAC prompt that needs to be permitted or denied on a secure desktop. No authentication is required.
- 3:  A value of 3 prompts for credentials.
- 4: A value of 4 prompts for consent by displaying the UAC prompt.
- 5: The default value of 5 prompts for consent for non-Windows binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Although this post may be outdated, have you considered running the account that requires a password prompt as a non-admin and then inputting the admin credentials? This may be the most effective approach.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).