# Windows 10: allow UAC require fingerprint but disable it on login

Tags: windows-10, administrator, uac, fingerprint, windows-hello

Is there a way to disable a fingerprint login for the administrator but leave this possibility enabled in an UAC prompt in Windows 10? After reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1085680/windows-10-make-uac-always-require-password) topic, I've set a value of 1 in the appropriate registry entry, so now it always requires a fingerprint or a PIN/password in the UAC prompt.

However, I don't want to allow the fingerprint login, but using gpedit

> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Biometrics -> Allow users to log on using biometrics

disables it everywhere, including the UAC prompt.
Is it possible to disable fingerprint only on login?

Comment: DIsable Fingerprint Login in Windows 10 Settings, User Accounts.   Restart and test. Fingerprint should still work in other settings. But even with Fingerprint enabled, UAC does not generally use it.

Comment: @John, Thank you for your answer! Do you mean this: [image](https://www.groovypost.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/2-Windows-Hello-fingerprint.png)?

Comment: Yes, that is the part (User Settings) I am suggesting to disable and try. I do not see much interaction between FP reader and UAC however.

Comment: @John, thank you, but it didn't work. After reboot, fingerprint was disabled both on login and in UAC. Now I'm able to login and authenticate in UAC only using PIN. UAC appears to be connected to Windows Hello...